# struct member may be uninitialised

Tags: c, gcc, struct

I'm currently writing a WebSocket Daemon for the ESP8266. I'm currently struggling with an error I can not explain. I defined a struct to hold all Information of a WebSocket Frame

```
typedef struct {
    uint8_t flags;
    uint8_t opcode;
    uint8_t isMasked;
    uint64_t payloadLength;
    uint32_t maskingKey;
    char* payloadData;
} WSFrame;
```

I then parse the message as described in [IEEE RFC6455 sec 5.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5). I then need to unmask the data, since I'm the server. Again, the [IEEE RFC6455 sec 5.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5) is very helpful here. However, the compiler for the xtensalx106 gives me the following error:

```
user/websocketd.c: In function 'wsRecvCb':
user/websocketd.c:104:11: error: 'frame.maskingKey' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Werror=maybe-uninitialized]
   WSFrame frame;
           ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

for the following piece of code:

```
WSFrame frame;
parseWsFrame(data, &frame);

os_printf("payloadLength=%"PRIu64"\n", frame.payloadLength);
unmaskWsPayload(frame.payloadData, frame.payloadLength, frame.maskingKey);
```

even though `frame.maskingKey` is defined in `parseWSFrame`.

What do I oversee? Why is it moaning about `'frame.maskingKey'` but does mention the error is in the initialisation?

If I do `frame.maskingKey = 0;` right after the definition of `WSFrame frame;`, the compiler shuts up. However, I can not declare uint32_t maskingKey = 0; in my struct definition.

I don't want to use any heap allocations, so I don't want to malloc anything.

Comment: What is `parseWsFrame()` function? why not initialize the struct like this: `WSFrame frame = FRAME_INIT;` where `FRAME_INIT` is `#define FRAME_INIT {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}`

Comment: I'm using `{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}` instead of `{0}` because some compilers still don't shuts up if you use the last one.

Comment: `maskingKey` is initialized in parseWsFrame conditionally, since it is not always needed

Comment: Is there possibly a code path through `parseWsFrame()` where `frame.maskingKey` might not get set? In other words, maybe it's generally initialized, but there is some corner case where it might not be, and the compiler is smart enough to recognize that?

Comment: @chuck258 But, given the code you've posted, `frame.maskingKey` is always needed, even if `unmaskWsPayload()` conditionally chooses to not use it, because it is being passed by value to `unmaskWsPayload()`, and the compiler is noticing that it is passing a possibly random/garbage value as a parameter...

Comment: @chuck258: If it's initialized in `parseWsFrame()` *conditionally* the compiler is right about it may be *uninitialised*.

Comment: yeah, it makes sense now. However, I didn't write C for a long time and forgot that variables are not automatically 0-initialized

Comment: If code temporarily replaces `parseWsFrame()` with a same signatured function that sets all fields, does the error go away?  If replaced with a function that sets all fields but `maskingKey`, does the same error occur?

Answer (score 1):

I think the main thing here is `-Werror` flag while compiling, which is treating the warning as error. And if you still want to keep that compiler flag, you better initialize the `frame.maskingKey` to `0`, as you did.

Initializing structure members in structure declaration is never allowed. So doing `uint32_t maskingKey = 0` is not possible inside structure declaration.

Comment: is this normal for c? I do really want the -Werror flag, but it seems like unnecessary code duplication

Comment: If you want -Werror flag you have to initialize the `frame.maskingKey` or the whole `frame` as told by @Jack